# How do I implement the functionality of Game Makers point_direction() function?

Tags: game-maker

I am trying to understand the logic behind Game Maker's `point_direction(x1, y1, x2, y2)` function, which takes the vector from `(x1, y1)` to `(x2, y2)` and returns the counter-clockwise angle it forms from the positive x-axis, in degrees.

[image: Image from the YoYo Games docs illustrating this function.]

([Diagram from the YoYo Games documentation of `point_direction`](https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/maths/vector%20functions/point_direction.html))

How do I implement this functionality in my own code?

Here's my attempt so far:

```
//custom_point_direction script

var x1 = argument0;
var y1 = argument1;
var x2 = argument2;
var y2 = argument3;
var targetAngle;

targetAngle = radtodeg(arctan2(y2,x1));


return -targetAngle;
```

Here's an example of how I want to use this function. This is the step event of an object that should face/point towards the player object:

```
direction = custom_point_direction(x,y,player_obj.x,player_obj.y);
image_angle = direction;
```

This does not work like GameMaker's `point_direction()` function. How do I make my `custom_point_direction()` work similar to `point_direction()`?

Comment: If you want the *functionality* of `point_direction()`, why don't you try *using* `point_direction()`?

Answer (score 2):

You missed `y1` and `x2` which not used in your formula, it must be

```
arctan2(y1 - y2, x1 - x2)
```

For same with GM you can use this formula:

```
-radtodeg(arctan2(y1 - y2, x1 - x2)) + 180;
```

See a small [example](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/78963719/stackoverflow/gml/point_direction.gmk).

Comment: I'd expect the opposite order of subtraction, ie. y2-y1, x2-x1 — though the difference would just be a 180 degree shift in the angle.